# linq2db - exception is thrown when using Lead function

Tags: c#, linq2db, linqkit

We are using .NET Core 3.1, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9), [Npgsql 4.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.1.9), [LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.2.3) and [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore 3.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore/3.7.0).

We have the following 2 scaffolded classes:

```cs
[Table("testrunconfig", Schema = "fit")]
public partial class Testrunconfig
{
    public Testrunconfig()
    {
        Testruntestgrp = new HashSet<Testruntestgrp>();
    }
    
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [InverseProperty("Testrunconfig")]
    public virtual ICollection<Testruntestgrp> Testruntestgrp { get; set; }
}

[Table("testruntestgrp", Schema = "fit")]
public partial class Testruntestgrp
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Column("testname")]
    public string Testname { get; set; }
    
    [Column("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TestrunconfigId))]
    [InverseProperty("Testruntestgrp")]
    public virtual Testrunconfig Testrunconfig { get; set; }
}
```

We enabled linq2db logging like this:

```cs
private void ConfigureLinq2DbConsoleLogging()
{
    DataConnection.TurnTraceSwitchOn();
    DataConnection.WriteTraceLine = (string s1, string s2, TraceLevel _) => Debug.WriteLine($"{s1}: {s2}");
}
```

We have a query where we need both LinqKit (to invoke `DetermineFinalResultForTestFunc`) and linq2db (to use SQL window function `LEAD`):

```cs
private readonly static Expression<Func<Testrunconfig, string, string>> DetermineFinalResultForTestFunc =
    (Testrunconfig trc, string testName) =>
        trc == null ?
            null :
            (trc.Finished == null ?
                "IN_PROGRESS" :
                (trc.Testruntestgrp == null || trc.Testruntestgrp.Any(x => x.Testname == testName && x.Status != "OK") ?
                    "ERROR" :
                    "OK")
                );

public void GetTestBisectedExecutions(string testName)
{
    var result = _fitDbContext.Testrunconfig
        .AsExpandable()
        .Include(x => x.Testruntestgrp)
        .Where(x => x.Testruntestgrp.Any(y => y.Testname == testName))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
        .Select(x => new TestExecutionHelper()
        {
            TestrunConfig = x,
            SelectedTestName = testName,
            FinalResultSelectedTest = DetermineFinalResultForTestFunc.Invoke(x, testName)
        })
        .Where(x => Sql.Ext.Lead(x.FinalResultSelectedTest, Sql.Nulls.Respect)
            .Over()
            .OrderByDesc(x.TestrunConfig.Id)
            .ToValue() != x.FinalResultSelectedTest
        )
        .ToLinqToDB()
        .ToList();
}
```

*What are we trying to do with this query?
The final `.Where(...)` with `Sql.Ext.Lead` keeps just the last item in each sequence of the same `FinalResultSelectedTest` values. Example (before this `Where`):*

| **TestrunConfig.Id** | **FinalResultSelectedTest** |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | WARNING |
| 6 | OK |
| 5 | OK |
| 4 | ERROR |
| 3 | ERROR |
| 2 | OK |
| 1 | OK |

*Example (after this `Where`):*

| **TestrunConfig.Id** | **FinalResultSelectedTest** |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | WARNING |
| 5 | OK |
| 3 | ERROR |
| 1 | OK |

However, when we execute this query, the following exception is thrown. If I remove `Where()` with `Lead`, there is no exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in linq2db.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The thread 0xad6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5244 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
To generate test code to diagnose the problem set 'LinqToDB.Common.Configuration.Linq.GenerateExpressionTest = true'.: DataConnection
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in linq2db.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyProject.Web.Controllers.TestExecutions.TestExecutionsController.IndexAlternate (MyProject.Web) in 18729.8556ms
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint 'MyProject.Web.Controllers.TestExecutions.TestExecutionsController.IndexAlternate (MyProject.Web)'
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.32\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.32\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.32\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<ReplaceParametersWithChangedType>b__0(Expression b)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform[T](ICollection`1 source, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(BinaryExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.ReplaceParametersWithChangedType(Expression body, IList`1 before, IList`1 after)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(UnaryExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.RegisterPreambles[TD,TKey](ExpressionBuilder builder, IQueryable`1 detailQuery)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.EnlistEagerLoadingFunctionality[T,TD,TKey](ExpressionBuilder builder, Expression mainQueryExpr, Expression`1 detailQueryLambda, Expression compiledKeyExpression, Expression`1 selectKeyExpression)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 19635.7644ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

---

### Update

I modified the query as suggested by Svyatoslav Danyliv. This is the query that I have now:

```cs
var result = _fitDbContext.Testrunconfig
    //.Include(x => x.Testruntestgrp)
    .Where(x => x.Testruntestgrp.Any(y => y.Testname == testName))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new TestExecutionHelper()
    {
        TestrunConfig = x,
        SelectedTestName = testName,
        FinalResultSelectedTest = DetermineFinalResultForTestFunc.Compile()(x, testName)
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Helper = x,
        NextVal = Sql.Ext.Lead(x.FinalResultSelectedTest, Sql.Nulls.Respect)
            .Over()
            .OrderByDesc(x.TestrunConfig.Id)
            .ToValue()
    })
    .Where(x => x.NextVal != x.Helper.FinalResultSelectedTest)
    .Select(x => x.Helper)
    .ToLinqToDB()
    .ToList();
```

However, it still throws an exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in linq2db.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
To generate test code to diagnose the problem set 'LinqToDB.Common.Configuration.Linq.GenerateExpressionTest = true'.: DataConnection
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in linq2db.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action MyProject.Web.Controllers.TestExecutions.TestExecutionsController.IndexAlternate (MyProject.Web) in 14310.6779ms
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint 'MyProject.Web.Controllers.TestExecutions.TestExecutionsController.IndexAlternate (MyProject.Web)'
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.32\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.32\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.32\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<ReplaceParametersWithChangedType>b__0(Expression b)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform[T](ICollection`1 source, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform[T](ICollection`1 source, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<TransformX>g__Modify|0(MemberBinding b)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform[T](ICollection`1 source, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MemberInitExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.ReplaceParametersWithChangedType(Expression body, IList`1 before, IList`1 after)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(UnaryExpression e, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c__DisplayClass49_1.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__2(Expression a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.<>c.<FinalizeExpressionKeys>b__49_0(Expression e)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.FinalizeExpressionKeys(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.RegisterPreambles[TD,TKey](ExpressionBuilder builder, IQueryable`1 detailQuery)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.EnlistEagerLoadingFunctionality[T,TD,TKey](ExpressionBuilder builder, Expression mainQueryExpr, Expression`1 detailQueryLambda, Expression compiledKeyExpression, Expression`1 selectKeyExpression)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.EagerLoading.GenerateDetailsExpression(IBuildContext context, MappingSchema mappingSchema, Expression expression)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.GetMultipleQueryExpression(IBuildContext context, MappingSchema mappingSchema, Expression expression, HashSet`1 parameters, Boolean& isLazy)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildMultipleQuery(IBuildContext context, Expression expression, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.TableContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, ParameterExpression parentObject)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.TableBuilder.TableContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.TransformExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expr, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass79_0.<BuildExpression>b__0(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expression, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.CorrectConditional(IBuildContext context, Expression expr, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.CorrectConditional(IBuildContext context, Expression expr, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.ConvertAssignmentArgument(IBuildContext context, Expression expr, MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.TransformExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expr, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass79_0.<BuildExpression>b__0(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expression, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.TransformExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expr, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass79_0.<BuildExpression>b__0(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expression, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.PassThroughContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<BuildExpression>b__0(IBuildContext ctx, Expression ex, Int32 l)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.ProcessScalar[T](Expression expression, Int32 level, Func`4 action, Func`1 defaultAction, Boolean throwOnError)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.TransformExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expr, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass79_0.<BuildExpression>b__0(Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr, Func`2 func)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.BuildExpression(IBuildContext context, Expression expression, Boolean enforceServerSide, String alias)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.BuildExpression(Expression expression, Int32 level, Boolean enforceServerSide)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.SelectContext.BuildQuery[T](Query`1 query, ParameterExpression queryParameter)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder.Build[T]()
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.CreateQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.Query`1.GetQuery(IDataContext dataContext, Expression& expr)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.GetQuery(Expression& expression, Boolean cache)
   at LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LinqToDBForEFQueryProvider`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MyProject.Service.TestExecutionsService.GetTestBisectedExecutions(String configuration, Int32 maxTransitions, String testName, String svnRevision) in E:\MyDevCheckouts\AsystSupportDB\MyProject_trunk\MyProject.Service\TestExecutionsService.cs:line 56
   at MyProject.Web.Controllers.TestExecutions.TestExecutionsController.IndexAlternate(BisectExecutionsGuiModel model) in E:\MyDevCheckouts\AsystSupportDB\MyProject_trunk\MyProject.web\Controllers\TestExecutions\TestExecutionsController.cs:line 98
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at DevExpress.AspNetCore.Internal.BinaryStorageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at DevExpress.AspNetCore.Internal.ResourceManagerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 15984.5845ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsExpandable()` should be placed after `ToLinqToDB()`.
`Lead` should be placed in `Select`, databases do not allow window functions in `Where` statement.

Also with `linq2db` you can omit LINQKit:

```cs
var result = _fitDbContext.Testrunconfig
    .Include(x => x.Testruntestgrp)
    .Where(x => x.Testruntestgrp.Any(y => y.Testname == testName))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new TestExecutionHelper()
    {
        TestrunConfig = x,
        SelectedTestName = testName,
        FinalResultSelectedTest = DetermineFinalResultForTestFunc.Compile()(x, testName)
    })
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        helper = x,
        next_value = Sql.Ext.Lead(x.FinalResultSelectedTest, Sql.Nulls.Respect)
            .Over()
            .OrderByDesc(x.TestrunConfig.Id)
            .ToValue()
    })
    .Where(x => x.next_vaue != x.FinalResultSelectedTest)
    .Select(x => x.helper)
    .ToLinqToDB()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I modified the query like you suggested, but it still throws an exception. Please see the "Update" section in my original question.

Comment: Try to remove `Include`. Looks like a bug in Eager Loading.

Comment: I removed `Include` like you suggested. Please see updated code snippet and exception in my original question in "Update" section.

Comment: Try to inline `DetermineFinalResultForTestFunc` expression into query. Just to exclude possible side effects. Also remove `trc.Testruntestgrp == null` - it is not needed and may cause translation problems.

Comment: It all works well when I removed `trc.Testruntestgrp == null` check. However, by removing `Include(x => x.Testruntestgrp)`, field `TestExecutionHelper.TestrunConfig.Testruntestgrp` always contains 0 elements in the final result. This is not what I want - I need this field to be populated because I show some of its data on the GUI.

Comment: Return `Include` back, If `Include` do not work, specify what is needed in `Select`.

Comment: If I add `Include(x => x.Testruntestgrp)` back, then the before mentioned expception occurs. I will have to return what is needed in `.Select(...)`. Thank you for your help. :)